# Passing system properties that contains spaces to Tomcat through JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, bash, shell, tomcat, tomcat6

I need to pass multiple system properties to Tomcat 6 through the JAVA_OPTS environment variable. I can't seem to pass system properties that contain spaces:

```
JRE_HOME=/root/jre1.6.0_34/ JAVA_OPTS="-DsysProp1=foo -DsysProp2=bar with spaces" ./catalina.sh run
```

Fails with:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /root/jre1.6.0_34/
Using CLASSPATH:       /root/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: with
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: with
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: with.  Program will exit.
```

I looked around on SO and the answers don't seem to help. Tried all of these with no success:

```
JRE_HOME=/root/jre1.6.0_34/ JAVA_OPTS="-DsysProp1=foo -DsysProp2=\"bar with spaces\"" ./catalina.sh run

JRE_HOME=/root/jre1.6.0_34/ JAVA_OPTS='-DsysProp1=foo -DsysProp2="bar with spaces"' ./catalina.sh run

JRE_HOME=/root/jre1.6.0_34/ JAVA_OPTS='-DsysProp1=foo -DsysProp2=bar\ with\ spaces' ./catalina.sh run
```

Comment: Could you show cataline.sh script? Maybe the problem is inside that script

Comment: catalina.sh is Tomcat's startup script, so I wouldn't want to modify it. You can take a look at it here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_6_0_34/bin/catalina.sh

Comment: I'm concerned at all your paths being under `/root` - I hope you're not running Tomcat as the root user...

Comment: It is a VM that I use for the sole purpose of testing :)

Comment: Still I would recommend running your tests as an unprivileged user, otherwise you're not really testing the same setup as you would be running in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative you could put the property settings into `conf/catalina.properties` instead of using `JAVA_OPTS`. This is a standard `java.util.Properties` format file so you don't need to quote anything, it simply takes everything before the first equals sign, colon or space as the property name and everything after that as the value:

```
sysProp2=bar with spaces
```

If you can't (or would prefer not to) modify that file directly, you can copy it to another location, edit the copy, and then pass

```
-Dcatalina.config=file:/path/to/copy/of/catalina.properties
```

in `JAVA_OPTS` to make it load your properties from there.

Comment: could you give an example of exactly what to write in `catalina.properties`?

Comment: @ElliottB I've added some more detail - it's a standard property file so no quoting required.

Comment: I tried the following line in catalina.properties but it doesn't have any effect. I tried adding garbage to the line as well, and it seems to be ignored by Tomcat. `-Djavax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine=#Nvidia [plughw:0,0]`

Comment: Ah thank you, that worked. But today I found this saying the preferred place to set JAVA_OPTS is in `CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh`. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Thanks for providing the link to the actual script.
Here is what `catalina.sh` does:

```
exec "$_RUNJAVA" "$LOGGING_CONFIG" $JAVA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS # ... more stuff
```

So it is going to be split by spaces no matter what you do. There is no way to fix that without changing  `catalina.sh` file.

This page answer the question in detail: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it will get split by spaces no matter what?

Comment: Because that is how word splitting works in bash. There is a reason why I added a link to bash faq. There are several solutions provided as well.